# Divergence in COMSOL

Tags: comsol

I'm trying to calculate the divergence of a vector quantity $L(L_x, L_y, L_z)$ in COMSOL. I calculate it using the built-in differentiation operator as follow:

$$\nabla L = d(L_x,x)+d(L_y,y)+d(L_z,z)$$

I'm wondering what is the notation or the function for divergence. Does COMSOL calculate the divergence of $L$ correctly in the way that I did in above?

Comment: Is $L$ a scalar or a vector in your case?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>First of all, your definition of the divergence is different from the [standard definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Application_in_Cartesian_coordinates). (Assuming you are in cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$, and $d(\cdot,x)$ means the partial derivative wrt $x$.</strike>

Regarding Comsol. When in cartesian coordinates, $\nabla \cdot L$ always gives you the divergence of a vector quantity $L$ <strike>in the sense linked above</strike>.

In different coordinate systems, $\nabla \cdot$ acts differently depending on the interface where you apply it. I would love to link to the corresponding entries of the Comsol documentation, but it is [not commonly available](http://www.comsol.com/community/forums/general/thread/23683/).